# How to upload Corel Draw files in OpenCart?

Tags: upload, opencart, coreldraw

Customers in my OpenCart store had requested the feature to upload Corel Draw files (.cdr) from product page by using the Upload File option. This is a file type extension that is not supported by default, and I am yet unable to incorporate it. What I've done so far:

In System > Settings > Server, I included **cdr** and **CDR** under *Allowed File Extensions*. Additionally, I've put all the MIME types I could find for *Allowed File Mime Types*:

- application/cdr
- application/coreldraw
- application/x-cdr
- application/x-coreldraw
- application/vnd.corel-draw
- image/cdr
- image/CDR
- image/x-cdr
- image/x-coreldraw
- zz-application/zz-winassoc-cdr

Unfortunately, OpenCart would still return "Invalid Extension Type" when I try to upload a Corel Draw X6 cdr file. I also tried to incorporate .torrent files (using the same approach - just for a test - and it worked), so I believe the answer to uploading **.cdr** files is close.

Comment: It looks like You may be missing some `mime type`. Add an `echo` on uploaded file's mime type to find out which one You are missing...

Comment: Sounds logical, shadyyx! Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to do that - could you please provide details / step-by-step ? I would really appreciate it!

Comment: Open up Your `catalog/controller/product/product.php` and scroll to the end where the `upload()` function should be. Here are the checks against allowed extensions and allowed MIME types done - so somewhere here You should place an `echo` or some logging to find out what PHP thinks Your MIME type is when uploading a `.cdr` file... When using an `echo` - the response is send back within the AJAX request, so don't forget to check Your Firebug's Console tab...

Comment: I'm sure you are right, though I couldn't make that work. Fortunately, thanks to you I "reverse-engineered" your idea, searched in Google for "how to check mime type" -> I then uploaded my file at http://mime.ritey.com/ , which suggested "application/octet-stream" --- And it works!

Comment: So what is the missing MIME? :-)

Comment: Turns out, the MIME type is: "application/octet-stream"

Comment: `application/octet-stream` is used when there are binary data of unspecified/unrecognized/unknown MIME type... I think it is used as a fallback for binary files and it should be already allowed... But obviously it is not :-) So let's add it to the allowed mime types and You should be done ;-)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it via the file manager in the admin backend you could make the following vqmod script and save it in your xml folder... this will allow you to add the cdr files into your site for dowload or for linking or anything via your file manager...

```
<modification>
<id>CDR File Uploader</id>
<version>1.2</version>
<vqmver>2.1.5</vqmver>
<author>Jeremy Fisk</author>
<file name="admin/controller/common/filemanager.php">
    <operation>
        <search position="before"><![CDATA[if (isset($this->request->get['image'])) {]]></search>
        <add><![CDATA[$ext = strrchr($this->request->get['image'], '.');
            if(strtolower($ext) == '.cdr') {
                $this->request->get['image'] = 'cdr_icon.png';
            }]]></add>
    </operation>
    <operation>
        <search position="after"><![CDATA['.jpg',]]></search>
        <add><![CDATA['.cdr',]]></add>
    </operation>
    <operation error="skip"><!-- 1.5.0.x - 1.5.1.2 only -->
        <search position="replace"><![CDATA[$this->model_tool_image->resize(substr($file, strlen(DIR_IMAGE)), 100, 100)]]></search>
        <add><![CDATA[(strtolower($ext) == '.cdr') ? $this->model_tool_image->resize('pdf_icon.png', 100, 100) : $this->model_tool_image->resize(substr($file, strlen(DIR_IMAGE)), 100, 100)]]></add>
    </operation>
    <operation error="skip"><!-- 1.5.1.3 only -->
        <search position="replace"><![CDATA[$this->model_tool_image->resize(utf8_substr($file, strlen(DIR_IMAGE)), 100, 100)]]></search>
        <add><![CDATA[(strtolower($ext) == '.cdr') ? $this->model_tool_image->resize('pdf_icon.png', 100, 100) : $this->model_tool_image->resize(utf8_substr($file, strlen(DIR_IMAGE)), 100, 100)]]></add>
    </operation>
    <operation>
        <search position="replace"><![CDATA[300000]]></search>
        <add><![CDATA[3000000]]></add>
    </operation>
    <operation>
        <search position="after"><![CDATA['image/jpeg',]]></search>
        <add><![CDATA[                'application/octet-stream',]]></add>
    </operation>
</file>
<file name="admin/language/english/common/filemanager.php">
    <operation>
        <search position="replace"><![CDATA[300kb]]></search>
        <add><![CDATA[3MB]]></add>
    </operation>
</file>
```

This will also increase your upload limit in the file manager n opencart to 3Mb (used to be 300Kb)

You will need to save a png file of a cdr icon in your default image location (called 
"cdr_icon.png")

I hope this little script helps

Cheers
Jeremy

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write a whole script, Jeremy! All seems good, though I didn't get the chance to test your solution - I was able to resolve the issue by adding "application/octet-stream" as a mime type instead.

Comment: No worries... sorry I couldn't help

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the above but its not working. The latest OpenCart 1.5.6.x Versions don't allow anything except image files to be uploaded through image manager. "[All file Types" extension](http://goo.gl/rm0NRz) (its a paid extension) worked.  However you need to set correct MIME type of coral files application/cdr